# SSH Proxy based on Key file

Tags: ssh, proxy

Ok i am looking for a method of handing multiple ssh from a single public ip address and a single port to multiple servers based on the ID file use to connect to the server.  I have considered using the ~/.bashrc to run a ssh connection to the private ip of the server but that is the only idea i have.  It has been hard to find any relevant info as searching anything with SSH and proxy ends with either forward or reverse proxy questions.

Best case scenario

```
user@publicip -i user1 --- proxy to user@192.168.1.10
user@publicip -i user2 --- proxy to user@192.168.1.20
```

I think i can make this work using ~/.bashrc

```
user1@publicip -i user1 --- proxy to user@192.168.1.10
user2@publicip -i user2 --- proxy to user@192.168.1.20
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are intending to do. SSH is a TCP protocol and TCP protocols by default choose their own source port. I guess it might therefore be very hard to force SSH to use a specific source port. Also I do not understand TCP enough to tell you whether TCP allows you to multiplex multiple connections onto **one single** source port but my guess would be no: TCP doesn't allow you to do that. In which case that wouldn't have to do anything with SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

I'm assuming you mean "single public IP address and a single public **inbound**/**destination** port".

In this case, you may have gone too far out in your search, as the answer probably was right at your fingertips all along: [the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT chapter in sshd(8) man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) will, I believe, give you exactly the tool you're looking for.

In the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for `user@publicip`, you can specify commands to run instead of a normal session whenever a particular key is used. So you can just do this:

```
command="ssh user@192.168.1.10",restrict,pty ssh-rsa <public key of user1>
command="ssh user@192.168.1.20",restrict,pty ssh-ed25519 <public key of user2>
```

With this `authorized_keys` file, if the private key of user1 is used to authenticate to `user@publicip`, `sshd` will immediately run `ssh user@192.168.1.10` **instead of the user's regular shell**. When the SSH connection to 192.168.1.10 ends, the entire session will end. And if the private key of user2 is used instead, it will connect to `user@192.168.1.20` respectively.

But if my assumption was incorrect and you really want to restrict the outbound side of the proxy to a single **source port**, there is a small matter of writing your own custom implementation of the TCP protocol and modifying a version of SSH to run on top of that first...

Comment: Thank you!!! just got done testing and it worked great!  Yep your assumption was spot om, though a entire custom tcp stack sounds tempting ill take this much simpler solution :)

Comment: I thought so. Sometimes a single missing word in the requirements is enough to make a difference between a simple thing and a big project :)